# ISAPI extensions in IIS Express?

Tags: delphi, iis-express, isapi

Hi I'd like to run & develop an ISAPI extension in IIS Express 7.5 on a Windows 7 x64 machine. Lets say that I have the ISAPI extension in C:\dev\mywebapp.dll. The dll is 32 bit native DLL written in Delphi. Then I can configure IIS to respond to requests like http://localhost/foo/mywebapp.dll?id=100. Does anyone know if I can use IIS Express 7.5 instead of the fullblown IIS for the same purpose?

I have tried using IIS Express 7.5 but when I go to my http://localhost:8080/mywebapp.dll my browser is asking me to save the dll. I'd like IIS Express to run it as an ISAPI extension like the full IIS would do. Ideas anyone?

TIA,

Johan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using IIS Express to debug my Delphi ISAPI Web Application.  The following page shows how to do this:

http://paul.klink.id.au/Software/Delphi/DebuggingIsapiWithIisExpress.htm

Comment: For Everyone who is stranded at this point, here is the Link to WayBackMachine: https://web.archive.org/web/20161231162824/http://paul.klink.id.au/Software/Delphi/DebuggingIsapiWithIisExpress.htm
The missing Link for me was changing <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
into
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
Do that in <IISExpress Installfolder>\AppServer\applicationhost.config

Answer (score 0):

Run following command from the IIS Express installation folder.

```
appcmd set config /section:handlers /+[name='MyIsapiExtension',path='*.aaa',verb='GET,POST',scriptProcessor='C:\dev\mywebapp.dll']
```

More info can be found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754147%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I still can not get my ISAPI extensiion to it to work properly with IIS Express. I guess I'll have to stick with the real thing and do my work as admin after all :(

Comment: What is the '*.aaa' part about?